# Google Web Starter Kit responsive navigation

Tags: frameworks

Anyone else try out Google Web Starter Kit yet (https://developers.google.com/web/starter-kit/) ? I've downloaded and run it, everything seems to run smoothly in set up and I have all the neccesary versions of node, grunt and sass, but when I run gulp serve to look at the compiled site the navigation doesn't flip to responsive on resize. Can't see any missing dependencies or errors in the console to see why it wouldn't work. I haven't adjusted any of the default markup, literally taken it as it is and run it, as far as I'm aware it should have the nav in by default.

Anyone else come across problem? Or even knows what's running that navigation so I should be especially looking out for?

Answer (score 0):

Try to emulate it ?

- (Google Chrome browser) Right Click > Inspect Element > Emulate
- (Mozila Firefox browser) Right Click > Inspect Elemement > Responsive
  Design Mode